# Equivalence of definition of absolute convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

### Definition

$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}a_n =s, s \in \mathbb{R} \Leftrightarrow \forall \varepsilon \gt 0 \space \exists \left( F\subseteq \mathbb{N}\wedge \left|F\right| \in\mathbb{N} \right) \left[ \forall G \subseteq \mathbb{N} \wedge F\subseteq G \wedge \left| \sum_{n \in G}a_n -s\right| \lt \varepsilon \right]$$
In words, Definition 1 claims that a real value $s$ is the sum of the series $a_n$ iff we can make a subsum over finite $F$ so that everything left is sufficiently small for any small $\varepsilon$.

### Absolute convergence

### $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\left| a_n\right|=s,s \in \mathbb{R}$$

### Question

Do these state the same for every series?

### Observations

It seemed profitable to think about reordering, but was especially messy when $G$ becomes infinite. 
Direct proof through definitions seemed too inconsistent to finish.
Basic convergence test fails horribly.

### Idea

I do have a feeling that this equivalence somehow connects to the axiom of choice for infinite $G$.

Comment: Please clarify what $|F|$ means. Additionally, if I pick any sequence such that $a_{3k}=0$, what in you definition is preventing me from picking $G={3,6,9,...,3k,...}$? And does the summation in bars on your definition assumes constant $s?$

Comment: Please don't mistake expressing everything by symbols as being "mathematical". Clear communication is critical in mathematics and such excessive use of symbolism very strongly gets in the way of that.

Comment: Definition 1 and absolute convergence are equivalent. However, the sum in the former won't necessarily be the sum in the later. If $p$ denotes the sum of the nonnegative terms and $n$ denotes the sum of the negative terms of your unsigned series, then definition 1 will result in $p+n$ as its limit. Absolute convergence will give $p-n$ as its limit.

Comment: @RianKoja $\left|F \right|$ is the cardinality of the set, in words the set $F$ is finite. $G$ can be any. The $s$ is constant and is meant to be the sum on the left side, if there is one.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks, I will try to be more descriptive next time, it is our uni's bad habit to make points without actually using language.

Comment: @Robert Fair point, I should have distinguished those two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On notation: if $G \subseteq \Bbb N$ is infinite, then $\sum_{n \in G} a_n$ represents the limit when the partial sums are added in increasing order of the indices.

I claim that the following statements about the series $\sum a_n$ are equivalent:

1. There exists $s \in \Bbb R$ such that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a finite set $F \subset \Bbb N$ such that for every $G$ with $F \subseteq G \subseteq \Bbb N$, $$\left|\sum_{n \in G} a_n - s\right| < \epsilon$$
2. Every subseries of $\sum a_n$ converges.
3. $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent.

Proof: 1) $\implies$ 2): Let $H \subseteq \Bbb N$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists a finite $F$ such that if $F \subseteq G$, then $\left|\sum_G a_n - s\right| < \frac \epsilon 2$. If $M \ge N > \max(F)$ and we set $G_1 =\{n \in \Bbb N\mid n < N\}$ and $G_2 = G_1 \cup \{n \in \Bbb N\mid n \le M \text{ and }n \in H\}$, then

$$\left|\sum_{n\in G_1} a_n - s\right| < \frac \epsilon 2\\\left|\sum_{n \in G_2} a_n - s\right| < \frac \epsilon 2$$
So
$$\left|\sum_{\underset{n \in H}{n=N}}^M a_n\right| = \left|\left(\sum_{n\in G_2} a_n - s\right) - \left(\sum_{n\in G_1} a_n - s\right)\right| \le \left|\sum_{n\in G_2} a_n - s\right| + \left|\sum_{n\in G_1} a_n - s\right| < \epsilon$$
Which is the Cauchy condition on the subseries $\sum_{n\in H} a_n$. Therefore it must converge.

2) $\implies$ 3): Let $P = \{n \in \Bbb N\mid a_n \ge 0\}$ and $N = \{n \in \Bbb N\mid a_n < 0\}$. Then both $\sum_{n\in P} a_n$ and $\sum_{n\in N} a_n$ converge. But $$\sum |a_n| = \sum_{n\in P} a_n - \sum_{n \in N} a_n$$ so it also converges (to fill in the details I am skipping, restrict all three series to $n \le K$ and let $K \to \infty$).

3) $\implies$ 1): Let $\epsilon > 0$ and let $s = \sum a_n$. Then there is an $M$ such that $$\left|\sum_{n\le M} a_n - s\right| < \epsilon/2$$
Since $\sum |a_n|$ converges, there is an $N$ such that $\sum_{n > N} |a_n| < \epsilon/2$. Let $F = \{n \in \Bbb N\mid n \le \max\{M,N\}\}$. If $G \supseteq F$ and $H = G \setminus F$, then 
$$\left|\sum_{n\in H}a_n\right| \le \sum_{n\in H} |a_n| \le \sum_{n > N} |a_n| < \epsilon/2$$
and
$$\left|\sum_{n\in G}a_n - s\right| = \left|\sum_{n\in F}a_n - s + \sum_{n\in H}a_n\right| \le \left|\sum_{n\in F}a_n - s\right| + \left|\sum_{n\in H}a_n\right| < \epsilon$$
Q.E.D.

Comment: The other direction of your claim IS true,

Comment: @DanielWainfleet - I figured it was, but it was late and I was tired and decided to work out the issue after I slept. I just didn't want to have to retype the part I'd finished.

Comment: I really enjoyed going through your proof, well done! There are a few questions / notes I would like to share.
$1\implies 2$: I suppose $M \in \Bbb N$ and $N \in \Bbb N$ and both exists because $F$ is finite.
$3 \implies 1$: I cannot see that $\sum_{n\in H} |a_n| \le \sum_{n > N} |a_n|$, but I will try some more. Just for consistency purposes, shouldn't $G$ and $H$ be switched?

I will look at it for some more time, it might be just me not understanding what should be clear, anyway - great piece of work!

Comment: I have tried the $3 \implies 1$ with some sets plugged in and my observations seems to imply that $M$ is restricted to be the largest $n$ in $G$ such that $\{ \forall k \le n \mid k \in G \}$ and $N$ is defined via the inequality $\sum_{n > N} |a_n| < \epsilon/2$.

Comment: $M$ is defined first. $F$ is defined from $M$ and $N$, and then $G$ is just an arbitrary set of indices that contains $F$, as per your condition. $H$ is everything in $G$ that is not in $F$, so it doesn't match the requirement on $G$ of your condition, so it should not be switched with $G$. $\sum_{n\in H} |a_n| \le \sum_{n > N} |a_n|$ because $H$ cannot contain any indices in $F$, and therefore every index in $H$ is greater than $N$. So every $|a_n|$ included in the LH sum is also included in the RH sum, and everything else in the RH sum is positive.